# Confirm event for logout not working properly

Tags: jquery

I had some trouble with logout button, so i use confirm(); with on click event on jQuery.
I use if statement for confirm that the user is click **Ok** or **Cancle**

Button script :

```
<a id="logout-btn">
    <p>Logout</p>
</a>
```

Script that working :

```
$("#logout-btn").on("click", function() {
    var acc = confirm("Are you sure want Logout?");
    if (acc == true) {
        window.location.href = "logout.php";
    }else{

    }
});
```

Script that isn't working :

```
$("#logout-btn").on("click", function() {
    var acc = confirm("Are you sure want Logout?");
    if (acc == true) {
        window.location.href = "../logout.php";
    } else {

    }
});
```

The different between script just different folder but the second script when i click **Cancel** it still logout, What is the problem??

Comment: That is not possible from the code you show. Where is the button? In a form? Or is there some dialog template running too?

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: but the first script is working

Comment: The two scripts are identical. There is no jQuery issue here. Just because the URL is different. Look in the network tab for what is actually happening - like a 404 that redirects to home

Comment: when i on other folder i have to use the second script, but why it doesnt working just because diferent url

Comment: Also if you use anchors, then `$("#logout-btn").on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault();`

Comment: ow thanks that work for using preventDefault